# sp_server_diagnostics suspended

Tags: sql-server

I have accidentally killed sp_server_diagnostics on SQL Server running on Amazon RDS, should I be worried about it?
How can I fix that? (I am not a DBA)
I can see that it is now in a Suspended status

Just want to specify how it happened: I was trying to kill some running queries using KILL #SPID#

I had something like that

| session id | query name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | query-1 |
| 124 | query-2 |
| 125 | sp_server_diagnostics |

I have accidentally used `KILL 125`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Amazon runs their RDS solution, however SQL Server runs the sp_server_diagnostics call in a system session and thus it shouldn't be possible to kill it.

If you were able to kill it then this was executed by a user (assuming this isn't an implementation detail of RDS) and thus I wouldn't particularly worry about it. `sp_server_diagnostics` is absolutely fine to run as a user.

In so far as to why it's sitting in suspended, unsure without more information as there is nothing to "rollback".